# Should I allow google to index Magento filters/attributes?

Tags: product-attribute, google

What are the pros and cons to allowing Google to index attributes/filters?
I have all SEO urls setup correctly and run a footwear store.
One possible url could be:

www.shoestore.com/size6/black/hiking-boots

Allowing google to index all of my attributes will create thousands of more URLs for google to crawl/index - could this be a negative?